# material UI on react vite ResponsiveAppBar.jsx: Unexpected token, const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, vite

I'm using react+vite+material ui, when i try the example [responsiveAppBar](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/)
I have error. Also I have tried the ButtonAppBar example from the same site, ButtonAppBar works fine because the code is simply without " = () => {} "

This is my ResponsiveAppBar file (the same as example)

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import AppBar from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Avatar from '@mui/material/Avatar';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Tooltip from '@mui/material/Tooltip';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import AdbIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Adb';

const pages = ['Products', 'Pricing', 'Blog'];
const settings = ['Profile', 'Account', 'Dashboard', 'Logout'];

function ResponsiveAppBar() {
  const [anchorElNav, setAnchorElNav] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleOpenNavMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    setAnchorElUser(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleCloseNavMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElNav(null);
  };

  const handleCloseUserMenu = () => {
    setAnchorElUser(null);
  };

  return (
    <AppBar position="static">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Toolbar disableGutters>
          <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href="/"
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' },
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls="menu-appbar"
              aria-haspopup="true"
              onClick={handleOpenNavMenu}
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Menu
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElNav}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'bottom',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'left',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElNav)}
              onClose={handleCloseNavMenu}
              sx={{
                display: { xs: 'block', md: 'none' },
              }}
            >
              {pages.map((page) => (
                <MenuItem key={page} onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{page}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
          <AdbIcon sx={{ display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' }, mr: 1 }} />
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            noWrap
            component="a"
            href=""
            sx={{
              mr: 2,
              display: { xs: 'flex', md: 'none' },
              flexGrow: 1,
              fontFamily: 'monospace',
              fontWeight: 700,
              letterSpacing: '.3rem',
              color: 'inherit',
              textDecoration: 'none',
            }}
          >
            LOGO
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
            {pages.map((page) => (
              <Button
                key={page}
                onClick={handleCloseNavMenu}
                sx={{ my: 2, color: 'white', display: 'block' }}
              >
                {page}
              </Button>
            ))}
          </Box>

          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 0 }}>
            <Tooltip title="Open settings">
              <IconButton onClick={handleOpenUserMenu} sx={{ p: 0 }}>
                <Avatar alt="Remy Sharp" src="/static/images/avatar/2.jpg" />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Menu
              sx={{ mt: '45px' }}
              id="menu-appbar"
              anchorEl={anchorElUser}
              anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              keepMounted
              transformOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',
              }}
              open={Boolean(anchorElUser)}
              onClose={handleCloseUserMenu}
            >
              {settings.map((setting) => (
                <MenuItem key={setting} onClick={handleCloseUserMenu}>
                  <Typography textAlign="center">{setting}</Typography>
                </MenuItem>
              ))}
            </Menu>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </Container>
    </AppBar>
  );
}
export default ResponsiveAppBar;
```

this is the browser error whith npm run dev

```
    [plugin:vite:react-babel] /var/www/html/lnavarroa.cl/public_html/vite-app-lnavarroa/src/components/ResponsiveAppBar.jsx: Unexpected token (23:65)
  26 |   const handleOpenUserMenu = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
/var/www/html/lnavarroa.cl/public_html/vite-app-lnavarroa/src/components/ResponsiveAppBar.jsx:23:65
21 |    const [anchorElUser, setAnchorElUser] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
22 |  
23 |    const handleOpenNavMenu = (event, React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
   |                                                                   ^
24 |      setAnchorElNav(event.currentTarget);
25 |    };
```

I have installed babel, but nothings works :(

Answer (score 0):

A one liner work for me is :

```
npm install @mui/icons-material
```